# readr::read_csv(), empty strings as NA not working

Tags: r, na

I was trying to load a CSV file (`readr::read_csv()`) in which some entries are blank. I set the `na=""` in `read_csv()` but it still loads them as blank entries.

```
d1 <- read_csv("sample.csv",na="") # want to load empty string as NA
```

Where `Sample.csv` file can be like following:-

```
Name,Age,Weight,City
Sam,13,30,
John,35,58,CA
Doe,20,50,IL
Ann,18,45,
```

`d1` should show me as following(using `read_csv()`)

```
  Name Age Weight City
1  Sam  13     30   NA  
2 John  35     58   CA
3  Doe  20     50   IL
4  Ann  18     45   NA
```

First and fourth row of City should have `NA` (as shown above). But in actual its showing blank there.

Comment: I tried with the example and it is working for me using `readr_0.2.2`

Comment: Works fine for me too

Comment: Can confirm. Did not work with `readr` 0.1.1; worked after upgrading to 0.2.2.

Comment: Thanks guys. older version had that issue. 0.2.2 works fine.

Comment: Voting to close as no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and verifying myself, the solution was to upgrade to `readr_0.2.2`.

Thanks to [fg nu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414455/fg-nu), [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) and [Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven)